# Detect External/Physical Mouse Movements and Clicks android

Tags: android, service, accessibility, mouseevent, mouselistener

How to listen to External/Physical OPTICAL MOUSE movements and clicks and also stimulate them

used onGenericMotionEvent but was only able to listen to the movements when the activity or the app was in foreground

now how do i listen to the movements and clicks from background service or anything else with necessary permissions ( need it for local & personal use so no problem about privacy , permissions and security )

how able to manipulate keyboard strokes with the help of accessibility service

is there a way to listen to the mouse movements and clicks in background , if not

how about overlaying ( or something similar ) the activity or app on the home screen with transparent background so will that workaround work , with stimulating clicks and drags on home screen ?

or some other workaround for this

why i need to do this ?
i want to control a game ( more specifically move the camera view accordingly to the mouse movements )

Comment: Similar to: [Map keys to touchscreen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224310/3573)